# Unversion and add to ignore list for multiple folders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In TortoiseSVN I can right click on a folder and select "Unversion and add to ignore list".

It works exactly as I need it. My projects have lots of folders that I need to unversion.

I have to unversion

```
c:/Project/Plugins/Plugin-ab/bin
c:/Project/Plugins/Plugin-cd/bin
c:/Project/Plugins/Plugin-ef/bin
```

I dont want to unversion other "bin" folders.

Is this feasible?

Comment: You have lots of folders that you need to unversion and then you list 3 folders, they are only an example? Where are the other `bin` folders that you want to unversion, in `c:/Project/Plugins/Plugin-gh/bin`, `c:/Project/Plugins/Plugin-ij/bin`? Why not gather a list of folders that you want to unversion, then right click on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

1. Open Windows explorer in a parent directory, above all your bin folders.
2. Enter `bin` in the search bar
3. After search is complete, control click to select all the bin folders you want to unversion and ignore.
4. Right click on one of the bin folders and choose `TortoiseSVN` -> `Unversion and add to ignore list` -> `Delete and ignore (X) items by name`

Comment: Nice and easy! Works as expected.

Comment: I have to wait 22 hours more.